# Select Data From a MySQL Database overload CPU

Tags: php, html, mysql, cpu-usage

I have a problem of slow table load. I saw that the query to 'Select Data From a MySQL Database' overload the CPU resulting in a slow data load on the HTML table.
This is the code:

```
<?php

$sql = "SELECT id, codice, fornitore, cod_forn, ubicazione, descrizione, package, quantita, u_m 
        FROM maglab";
$result = $conn->query($sql);
//if ($result->num_rows > 0) {
if (!empty($result) && $result->num_rows > 0) {
    // output data of each row
    while ($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
        $id = $row['id'];
        $codice = $row['codice'];
        $fornitore = $row['fornitore'];
        $cod_forn = $row['cod_forn'];
        $ubicazione = $row['ubicazione'];
        $descrizione = $row['descrizione'];
        $package = $row['package'];
        $quantita = $row['quantita'];
        $u_m = $row['u_m'];

        echo "<tr>";
        //echo "<td>" .$id ."</td>";
        echo "<td>" .$codice ."</td>";
        echo "<td>" .str_replace(" - ", "<br>", $fornitore) ."</td>";
        echo "<td>" .str_replace(" - ", "<br>", $cod_forn) ."</td>";
        echo "<td>" .wordwrap($descrizione, 35, "<br />", true) ."</td>";
        echo "<td>" .$package ."</td>";
        echo "<td>" .$ubicazione ."</td>";
        echo "<td>" .$alert ."</td>";
        echo "<td>" .$u_m ."</td>";
```

```
<!-- Script per Bootstrap table -->
    <script src="https://unpkg.com/bootstrap-table@1.15.5/dist/bootstrap-table.min.js"></script>

<script> <!-- https://www.experts-exchange.com/questions/29070387/Print-button-in-dataTables.html -->
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#example').DataTable({
        deferRender: true,
        responsive: true,
        dom: 'Bfrtip',
        ordering: false, // false to disable sorting (or any other option)
        buttons: [
            { extend: "print", text: ' Stampa', className: 'btn btn-warning glyphicon glyphicon-print', footer: true,
                customize: function(win)
                {
 
                    var last = null;
                    var current = null;
                    var bod = [];
 
                    var css = '@page { size: landscape; }', // Stampa in orizzontale
                        head = win.document.head || win.document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0],
                        style = win.document.createElement('style');
 
                    style.type = 'text/css';
                    style.media = 'print';
 
                    if (style.styleSheet)
                    {
                      style.styleSheet.cssText = css;
                    }
                    else
                    {
                      style.appendChild(win.document.createTextNode(css));
                    }
 
                    head.appendChild(style);
                }
            },  
            { extend: 'excelHtml5', text: ' Esporta Excel', className: 'btn btn-danger glyphicon glyphicon-list-alt', footer: true  },            
            { extend: 'pdfHtml5', text: ' Esporta PDF', orientation: 'landscape', className: 'btn btn-primary glyphicon glyphicon-file', footer: true  }
    ],
    /*"language": {
    "url": "//cdn.datatables.net/plug-ins/9dcbecd42ad/i18n/Italian.json"
    }*/
});     
$('.dataTables_length').addClass('bs-select');

// Setup - add a text input to each footer cell
$('#example tfoot th').each( function () {
    var title = $(this).text();
    $(this).html( '<input type="text" placeholder="'+title+'" />' );
} );

// DataTable
var table = $('#example').DataTable();

// Apply the search
table.columns().every( function () {
    var that = this;

    $( 'input', this.footer() ).on( 'keyup change clear', function () {
        if ( that.search() !== this.value ) {
            that
                .search( this.value )
                .draw();
            }
        } );
    } );
});     
</script>
```

the pagination and the search under each column are activated. The table shows only 10 lines per page as you can see from the image

[image]

The same problem shows up in a HTML select tag that use a similar PHP code to load data from an SQL table (1500 lines vs 6000 of maglab)

Is there a way to solve the problem?

Comment: Your program fetches all rows from your `maglab` table in an unpredictable order. Simple queries like yours don't overtax MySQL (unless `maglab` is actually a complex VIEW rather than a table).It's possible your table has so many rows that your php program is running out of RAM. Please [edit] your question to explain more.

Comment: You're probably searching for a way to paginate your data, so you only show a limited amount of rows. The tool I happen to use for this is [Datatables](https://datatables.net), but I am sure there are alternatives. Whatever you choose, this does require a bit of work on your part.

Comment: @O.Jones Post edited. The problem don't involve RAM that ramain stable but the CPU usage moves from 2% to peaks of 90%. I have an Intel(R) Core(TM) i7-4770K CPU @ 3.50GHz  and 8.00 GB of RAM

Comment: When I see a web page with 6000 lines, I complain to the designer.  _That_ is the real problem.  You say there is "pagination" but I don't see that in the SQL.  600 pages is still a problem.

Comment: Sorry, if you look the image, really are 1400 items in 140 pages, not 6000 but its the same. I have a pagination, i show 10 items per page, but i know the PHP loads all the 1400 items and then shows 10 items per page. I'm not an expert, i think this is for item search. When i'm looking for an item from a search box, it search on the 1400 items loaded.

Comment: See [server side processing for your pagination](https://datatables.net/manual/server-side)

Comment: Any SELECT xxx FROM your_table that does NOT have a WHERE is expected to deliver ALL ROWS.